# Can I use non-canonical share folder paths?

Tags: unix, environment-variables

I am working under linux/unix (ubuntu centos darwin)

I often build from source and install my *biotools* folders in a non-canonical place in order to have full write access to that place for all users and also to avoid overwriting/conflicting with important files placed by the OS in **/usr/...** and **/usr/local/...**

I put the tool build folders in **/opt/biotools** and alias all exe files in **/opt/biotools/bin** (which is in my PATH)

Now some apps need to access dependencies or libraries usually written in **/usr/local/share** or **/usr/local/lib**, ...

Is it possible to add such folders like **/opt/biotools/share**, **/opt/biotools/lib**, ... and have the system find them?

Should I add these folders to the **PATH**?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Probably `PATH` is not what you need. Can you be more specific, what in `/opt/biotools/share` or `/opt/biotools/lib` would be needed by other applications?

Comment: Insufficient information. But assuming, for argument sake, you're putting library files (e.g., *libbiotools.a* or *libbiotools.so*) in your non-standard location your question is "how to get the compiler to automatically search that directory for your library files?" The details depend on information you haven't given us, but the answer basically boils down to tell the other person to add `-L/optbiotools/lib` to the compiler command to build their program.

Comment: Thanks all and especially Kurtis. This is what I needed. I think that some app builds are dependent on original libs when not made static and my way was leading to runtime errors. Will try this method.